# Mysql degsin fast to select

Tags: mysql, database-design

Who has some good idea for fast to login and other opration when I have more then 1,000,00~500,000,00 data in one table(Mysql)

Table:UserInfo(more then 1,000,00~500,000,00 Users)

```
UserID(PK int) LoginName(UK varchar(50)) LoginPassword LastLoginTime
```

Table:LoginLog

```
LogID(PK) UserID(FK) LoginTime LoginIp
```

Table3:others

```
OtherID(PK) UserID(FK) Others...
```

When the use login I use the sql (it is can fast) :

```
select LoginPassword from UserInfo where LoginName = 'string'
```

When i show LoginLog or other tables, I will use the SQL:

```
select U.LoginTime, 
       U.LoginIp,
       U.UserID,
       L.LoginName 
from UserInfo U 
left join LoginLog L 
  on U.UserID=L.UserID 
limit 0,10
```

I use partition by LoginName in UserInfo table (it is can fast login), but Associated query was very slow.

Split Table? partition use UserID?

Who has a better solution, split the table rules, partition rules?

Comment: Question for server fault?

Comment: @Akshay Just too much data

Comment: Not sure the join is the issue, rather that you are bringing back millions of records (and then just ignoring any after the first 10).

Comment: 1000 - 50000 users or 1000000 - 50000000 ? either you're lacking a 0 or mixing thousands and decimal separator.

Comment: @STTLCU about One hundred thousand to five million

Answer (score 1):

You could run a cron every 30 mins or so to denormalize data so that there are no table joins. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization

Comment: If it helps, get a +1. If it solves the issue, mark as correct answer. Nevertheless, it's a good practice to wait at least 24 hours before marking any answer as correct.